# VPN MFA (Keycloak) with openconnect

Tags: linux, vpn, multi-factor-authentication, openconnect

I am trying to deploy a VPN with dual authentication. While reading the ocserv documentation, I found the oicd option (https://gitlab.com/openconnect/ocserv/-/blob/master/doc/README-oidc.md). I am now trying to link my VPN with my sso Keycloack.

My configuration:

*/etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf* :

```
auth = "oidc[config=/etc/ocserv/oidc.json]"
```

*/etc/ocserv/oidc.json* :

```
{
    "openid_configuration_url": "http://10.1.1.1:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "user_name_claim": "preferred_username",
    "required_claims": {
    "aud": "http://10.1.1.1:8080/auth/realms/master",
    "iss": "http://10.1.1.1:8080/auth/realms/master"
    }
}
```

When launching the ocserv (version 1.1.6), I can see the Keycloak SSO configuration record showing the openid-configuration:

```
ocserv[590033]: main: initialized ocserv 1.1.6
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: reading supplemental config from files
ocserv[590034]: ocserv-oidc: fetched new JWK XXX
ocserv[590034]: ocserv-oidc: fetched new JWK XXX
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: loaded 1 keys
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: sec-mod initialized (socket: /run/ocserv.socket.1891ca24.0)
```

When I try to connect either with the openconnect in cli (on Debian or Fedora), my client can't connect and fails.

```
# openconnect --protocol=anyconnect https://10.1.1.1 --servercert pin-sha256:XXX -v
POST https://10.1.1.1/
Attempting to connect to server 10.1.1.1:443
Connected to 10.1.1.1:443
SSL negotiation with 10.1.1.1
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on 10.1.1.1
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Content-Length: 0
HTTP body length:  (0)
Server '10.1.1.1' requested Basic authentication which is disabled by default
GET https://10.1.1.1/
Attempting to connect to server 10.1.1.1:443
Connected to 10.1.1.1:443
SSL negotiation with 10.1.1.1
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on 10.1.1.1
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: webvpncontext=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 250
X-Transcend-Version: 1
HTTP body length:  (250)
Please enter your username.
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Server side:

```
ocserv[590033]: main: added 1 points (total 1) for IP '10.2.2.2' to ban list
ocserv[590123]: main: map worker serving remote address 10.2.2.2:20264 to secmod instance 0
note: vhost:default: setting 'oidc' as primary authentication method
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: received request from pid 590123 and uid 0
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: cmd [size=57] sm: sign
note: setting 'file' as supplemental config option
ocserv[590123]: worker: 10.2.2.2 accepted connection
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: received request from pid 590123 and uid 65534
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: cmd [size=38] sm: sign hash
ocserv[590123]: worker: 10.2.2.2 TLS handshake completed
ocserv[590123]: worker: 10.2.2.2 sending message 'session info' to main
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:20264 main received worker's message 'session info' of 66 bytes
ocserv[590123]: worker: 10.2.2.2 User-agent: 'Open AnyConnect VPN Agent v8.05-1'
ocserv[590123]: worker: 10.2.2.2 Detected OpenConnect v4 or newer
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:20264 worker terminated
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:20264 user disconnected (reason: unspecified, rx: 0, tx: 0)
ocserv[590033]: main: added 1 points (total 2) for IP '10.2.2.2' to ban list
ocserv[590124]: main: map worker serving remote address 10.2.2.2:16254 to secmod instance 0
note: vhost:default: setting 'oidc' as primary authentication method
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: received request from pid 590124 and uid 0
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: cmd [size=57] sm: sign
note: setting 'file' as supplemental config option
ocserv[590124]: worker: 10.2.2.2 accepted connection
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: received request from pid 590124 and uid 65534
ocserv[590034]: sec-mod: cmd [size=38] sm: sign hash
ocserv[590124]: worker: 10.2.2.2 TLS handshake completed
ocserv[590124]: worker: 10.2.2.2 sending message 'session info' to main
ocserv[590124]: worker: 10.2.2.2 User-agent: 'Open AnyConnect VPN Agent v8.05-1'
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:16254 main received worker's message 'session info' of 66 bytes
ocserv[590124]: worker: 10.2.2.2 Detected OpenConnect v4 or newer
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:16254 worker terminated
ocserv[590033]: main:10.2.2.2:16254 user disconnected (reason: unspecified, rx: 0, tx: 0)
```

The problem seems to come from the client openconnect that can't handle the oidc part. Has anyone ever successfully logged in with this authentication method on ocserv?

Thanks for your help !